# Node.js How to use stdin stream to read user input after reading from shell pipe

Tags: node.js, stdin, prompt, node.js-stream

After I receive data from shell pipe I need to ask user via prompt. But the application closes immediately after data is read from pipe. Hot to make it wait for user input?

```
var readline = require('readline');

var data = '';
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
process.stdin.on('readable', function() {
  var chunk = process.stdin.read();
  if (chunk !== null) {
    data+=chunk;                
  }
}); 

process.stdin.on('end', function() {

  console.log('from pipe: ' + data);

  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });

  rl.question('prompt> ', (answer) => {
    console.log('from prompt: ', answer);
    rl.close();
  });
});
```

When I run this script

```
$ echo "pipe" | node app.js
```

It prints

```
from pipe: pipe

prompt>
```

and exits immediately and never waits for prompt.

I'm on Windows, Node v4.2.1

Comment: You are calling `rl.close()` in the question so it closes out. Remove it and only close it when you are actually done.

Comment: Looks like Node thread does not waits for event handlers.

Comment: @aug `rl.close()` actually is not getting called. Code execution does not go into `question` callback.

Comment: @S.D. It does wait for timeout though:  if I replace manipulation with `readline` with 
`setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('waited');
  }, 1000);` 
it will print out 'waited'

Comment: When you use pipes, that IS a stdin. Propaply you want to use TTY after you read all the stdin

Answer (score 0):

Like @AlexeyTen says in the commens, use the [ttys](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ttys) package, or similar that uses the tty, for the input that needs to be from the console.

```
var ttys = require('ttys');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: ttys.stdin,
    output: ttys.stdout
});
```

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me when stdin was being suppressed by mocha. Instead I used [readline-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline-sync)

```
function promptToContinue()
{  
   const readlineSync = require('readline-sync');

   if (readlineSync.keyInYN("WARNING this will destroy your file.\n Press [Y/n] to continue> " ))
   {
      // User pressed Y or y
      return;
   } else {
      process.exit(-1);
   }
}
```